# How to read a file (Synchronously?) in a while loop in javascript (Discord.js)?

Tags: javascript, while-loop, discord.js, synchronization, filereader

This is possibly a duplicate question, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Essentially, I am making a code that runs in a while loop where I need to then read a file within that while loop, and it seems that the fileRead in the code just stops the while loop from getting to the end. I'm pretty newbie to javascript still, so it's probably an easy fix.

What I've tried so far is changing my jsonReader function to sync (readFileSync) and that just stopped the code before it did hardly anything. (that is now what the current code is as) I've also tried making a second function for specifically reading the files I need Synchronously and that didn't seem to work either. I'm not even sure if this has to do with synchronism

My Code:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'xprun',
    description: "runs the xp handler",
    execute(message) {
 
        const name = message.author.username;
        const server = message.guild.id;
 
        const fs = require('fs');
 
        function jsonReader(filePath, cb) {
            fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf-8', (err, fileData) => {
                if (err) {
                    return cb && cb(err);
                }
                try {
                    const object = JSON.parse(fileData);
                    return cb && cb(null, object);
                } catch (err) {
                    return cb && cb(err);
                }
            });
        }
 
        console.log('Starting the loop...'); //
        
        var run = true;
        var i = 0;
 
        while (run == true) {
            i++
 
            console.log('Running the loop...'); // Loop stops and re-runs here
 
            // read #1
 
                jsonReader(`./userData/rank/${server}_server/1.json`, (err, data) => {
 
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    } else {
                        console.log(data.id); //
                    }
 
            // read #2
 
                jsonReader(`./userData/xp/${server}_server/${name}_xp.json`, (err, data) => {
 
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    } else {
                        console.log(data.rank); //
                    }
 
                    console.log('The loop was completed'); //
                    
                    if (i >= 5) {
                        run = false;
                    }
 
                }); // end read #1
 
            }); // end read #2
 
        } // end while
 
        console.log('The loop was ended'); //
 
    } // end execute
 
} // end
```

Comment: Instead of the current code in your question, can you provide the code for your attempt to use `readFileSync`? That is most likely closer to the answer than the current provided code. Also, are there any errors in the console (e.g. when the code "stops" as you mentioned)? Can you also shorten this code down so that *only* the relevant code is provided? We don't need to see the rest of the code, it just makes it harder to read your code. Just include `jsonReader` and just the relevant parts of the `while` loop.

Comment: Surely! Please note that the files being read do in fact exist, and can be read from when I don't use my code outside of the while loop.

I'll need to edit my original question to fit the code still, so please look back up at that to see it.

Comment: There isn't an error with the code, like, it doesn't output an error, but rather it just continues to output "Running the loop..." and never stops

Comment: `readFileSync` doesn't take a callback.

Answer (score 0):

As @CherryDT mentioned in the comments, `readFileSync` does not accept a callback. Because `readFileSync` is synchronous, it does not need a callback; `readFile` accepts a callback only because it is asynchronous, because it needs to wait until it has read the file before calling the code in the callback. The synchronous method does not need to wait in this way, so you can move the callback code out of the callback like so:

```js
function jsonReader(filePath, cb) {
    try {
        const fileData = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf-8');
        const object = JSON.parse(fileData);
        return cb && cb(null, object);
    } catch (err) {
        return cb && cb(err);
    }
}
```

The reason your loop was infinitely running was because you set `run` to `false` only within your callback `cb` method, but because `readFileSync` does not accept a callback, your callback was never being run. With the above code, your callback should now be running, and the loop should no longer run infinitely (unless there are other issues within your callbacks).